# Is there a way to change GNOME wallpaper change from fade effect to crude replace?

Tags: gnome, compiz, desktop-background

I'm user of Wallch. Wallpaper changing makes my 2x 2 GHx proc choking if the video is being  played at the time. Or put programming work instead of watching video, that results delayed actions.

I've reported the bug to Wallch devs https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1340980 and it seems depended on GNOME, not Wallch.

I'd be glad for a way to simply disable fade effect for wallpaper change.

---

Edit: for now I've given up and just modified wallpaper change `delay` to 2 hours... No answers :( .

Comment: My advise is to use other tool than walch. I've used walch and it's heavy on the system, just use `feh`or some other cli tool to change your wallpapers

Answer (score 0):

I use the program [variety](https://launchpad.net/variety):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install variety
```

It has lots of good options.